Is there a reason to prefer setting environment variables in the shell vs. editing Renviron files?
I have R installed in a conda environment. I am particularly interested in setting library paths for R (R_LIBS_USER and R_LIBS_SITE), but my question is more generally about recommendations (and reasons) for setting environment variables that will be used by R.
R startup processes Renviron files in the following order:

R_HOME/etc/Renviron on Linux only [1]
R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site (Not created by default in conda env)
./.Renviron (a project-specfic file) or ~/.Renviron (a user-specific file)

It is recommended to not edit R_HOME/etc/Renviron. This file contains the following lines:
R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER:-'%U'}
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE:-'%S'}

These lines set R_LIBS_USER and R_LIBS_SITE in R to the value of the environment variables of the same name if they are non-empty, and otherwise uses default values that are explained in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html.
I want to set R_LIBS_USER to other than the default value, and want that value to apply to instances of R that run in this conda environment. Therefore, it seems I should create and edit R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site (processed 2nd in R startup). Changing ~/.Renviron would not be ideal, since I could run multiple R installations in different conda environments, and changes to ~/.Renviron would apply to all of them, whereas I want each environment to be sandboxed.
I can set the environment variables in the conda environment as follows:
conda env config vars set KEY=VALUE

For example:
conda env config vars set R_LIBS_USER=/path/to/user/library

Alternatively, I could create R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site and add the following line:
R_LIBS_USER=\path\to\user\library

Either of these methods will work. Is there any reason to prefer one to the other?
[1] On Unix versions of R there is also a file ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron’ which is read very early in the start-up processing. It contains environment variables set by R in the configure process. Values in that file can be overridden in site or user environment files: do not change ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron’ itself. Note that this is distinct from ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site’. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html
